# Any way to run Docker For Mac in only a couple GB of RAM?

Tags: macos, docker, ram, docker-for-mac

Docker For Mac is demanding 4GB of available RAM.

That is a much larger overhead than I have seen before for VMs.

Is there any way to run Docker on Mac without so much RAM?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these settings - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#advanced
I have been running Docker Desktop on Mac with these settings for a long time without no issues until you run some heavy workloads on it.
[image]

Comment: I would but it appears you have to run docker _first_ to even access these settings, no?

Comment: Yes, these settings are accessible only after installation. How much RAM do you have on your system? Try stopping some applications which are consuming more memory and then to run the installer if you get that error during initial installation.